# Civi does not send circular letters to all contacts in our distribution list. Why?

Tags: civimail, contacts

I send a circular letter to one of my companies distribution lists. On that list we have 107 contacts. In the report of the circular letter it reads that Civi send the letter to 94 contacts. The letter bounced in the case of 2 of those recipients, but that is not the issue.  There are 11 contacts that did not get the letter because Civi did not try to send it to those contacts. Now I am scratching my head, why?

I checked and all 11 contacts have a valid E-Mail address and the box for bulk mailing is checked for those E-Mail addresses. What else could it be that they are not included in the list of recipients for our circular letters?

Any help/idea is appreciated!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

There are several reasons why Civi would not send an email. I'm pretty sure this list will be missing at least one of those.  I'm assuming you're using bulk email as it's over 50 recipients.

1. Duplicate email address (2 or more contacts with the same email address)
2. Email address is on hold (maybe from a previous bounce)
3. Contact has 'Do not email' set on in comms preferences
4. Contact opted out of bulk emails

Comment: This is an obvious and frequent question, I wonder if this answer could be included either in the in-line help or the documentation.